# Поле с модификатором static, в разных классах будет ссылка на один и тот же объект?

Tags: java

есть класс In.class, умеющий хранить булевское значение
в классе А создаем поле public static In in = new In();  и устанавливаем ему значение 1

в классе B создаем такое же поле и присваиваем значение 2

Если из класса C обратиться к А.in.value какое он вернет значение?
Если из класса С затем обратиться к B.in.value какое в этом случае?

Comment: Может вы все-таки код напишите, а не будете писать "в классе таком-то создадим то-то"?

Comment: Вы дважды пишете `new ln()` -> создаётся два объекта. И насчет "какое он вернет значение" в целом - так ведь это легко проверяется самостоятельно. Если бы вопрос был "почему `А.in.value` равно `1`, а  `B.in.value` равно `2`?" - это бы уже было другое дело.

Comment: Непонятно как классу, хранящему буллево значение присвоить 1. Приведите пример кода.